# tidyr / dplyr performance: CRAN R vs. MRAN Microsoft R Open

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, tidyr, cran

When I read about Microsoft R Open I ususally read that it is faster in matrix calculations that R from CRAN due to multicore support.

I understand that this can increase performance e.g. when running regressions. Does it also significantly increase calculations from tidyr or dplyr? The underlying question is, i guess, whether these packages rely on matrix calculations or not. More generally, do data.frames work with matrix calculations under the hood? As far as I know, data.frames are a special kind of a list...

Does anyone have an answer to this. Theoretically ans (ideally) some benchmarks?

Comment: I did some benchmarks using RevoScaleR with data.table/dplyr/base R on 1e8 dataset.  For modeling, it is very efficient when compared to lm.  But, for other cases, reading/transforming/merge etc, i found it to be slower.  May be, it will be better when the dataset size increases.

Comment: Is it also not possible to improve matrix calculations by using a better BLAS library yourself. I am relatively sure that Open BLAS is optimised for parallel execution. I am sure there is a blog post somewhere about improving performance of R by changing your BLAS library. I will see if I can dig it out

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/for-faster-r-use-openblas-instead-better-than-atlas-trivial-to-switch-to-on-ubuntu/ is one of many such articles if you google search R and BLAS libraries